# Rails Paypal Express Error: Please enter a valid credit card number and type

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paypal, paypal-sandbox, activemerchant

I am trying to use paypal express checkout on my rails app and I keep getting the "Please enter a valid credit card number and type." error. Here's my code

in the model:

```
def process(order)
  return true if !self.new_record?

  ActiveMerchant::Billing::Base.mode = Piggybak.config.activemerchant_mode
      calculator = ::PiggybakPaypal::PaymentCalculator::Paypal.new(self.payment_method)
      self.month = Time.now.month
      self.year = Time.now.year
      order_total = (order.total_due * 100).to_i
      res = calculator.gateway.purchase(order_total, express_purchase_options)

  if res.success?
      return true
    else
      logger.debug "This is from debug"
      order.errors.add :payment_method_id, res.message.to_s
      return false
  end
end

def express_purchase_options
{
  :ip => request.remote_ip,
  :token => self.token,
  :payer_id => self.payer_id
}
end
```

Right now I'm really confused. Is it the option I send in wrong? If so how can I check it? Or is it the way I use paypal gateway wrong? I search around and someone said paypal sandbox might cause the problem?

Comment: That particular isn't something that would come back from an Express Checkout request because you don't pass any card data in those requests.  It sounds to me like your library must actually be hitting one of the credit card APIs instead of what you think it is, and since you don't have such data included, you're getting that error back.  Are there logs you can use to see the raw API request and response?